# nested, depended callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, nested

I am quite new to the callback hell (but i understand its meaning more and more now)

The setup:

- getAccessToken: call to get an accesstoken from an api
- getUserID:with access token, get a userID from an api
- getUserDetails: With userID get userdetails from an api
- postUserDetails: post retrieveduserdetails to an api

I need to pass values down the calls:

> getAccessToken *token* -> getUserID(token) *userID*
>   ->getUserDetails(userID) *userDetails* -> postUserDetails(userDetails)

in my naivity i thought i could get something running like:

```
postUserDetails(getUserDetails(getUserID(getAccessToken())));
```

or the other way round (where i would need to change the naming convention but i tried around so much that i ended up entangled in the below

```
getAccessToken(getUserID(getUserDetails(postUserDetails)))
```

What is the logical structure to get something like the below with asynchronous  ajax calls working? How can I pass down multiple callbacks that get values from the previous call?

Am i relying on any framework (like async) to get a     postUserDetails(getUserDetails(getUserID(getAccessToken()))) working?

Comment: One option: use `async/await` and `await` each asynchronous call, by using `Fetch`, which returns a `Promise`.

Comment: ^ for this particluar fiece of code, I'd prefer an actual Promise chain `getAccessToken().then(getUserID).then(getUserDetails).then(postUserDetails);` over async/await `postUserDetails(await getUserDetails(await getUserID(await getAccessToken())));` or `let token = await getAccessToken(); let userId = await getUserID(token); let userDetails = await getUserDetails(userId); postUserDetails(userDetails);`

Comment: *"Am i relying on any framework (like async) to get a postUserDetails(getUserDetails(getUserID(getAccessToken()))) working?"* I'd not reccomend that you'd implement your code like this, because this means that your function would need to be able to deal with Promises as arguments; that's overhead that imo doesn't belong there. For my example with the promise-chain you may only need a polyfill for `Promise`s, depending on what browser you target. If you want to use `async/await` in production, you'd probably need a preprocessor like [Babel](https://babeljs.io)

Comment: @Thomas that is exactly the problem, I need to pass values down the calls in example
 getAccessToken <token> -> getUserID <userID> ->getUserDetails <userDetails> -> postUserDetails
I don't know if that was clear from my question, i will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to pass values down the calls in example getAccessToken  -> getUserID  ->getUserDetails  -> postUserDetails I don't know if that was clear from my question

yes, values, but not the promises themselves.

a simple mock of your code:

```js
//your call chain
getAccessToken()
  .then(getUserID)
  .then(getUserDetails)
  .then(postUserDetails)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Done");
  })

//a mock of your code

//a utility to "simulate" the delay of a server call and return a Promise
function wait(delay) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
}

function getAccessToken() {
  console.log("getAccessToken");
  //mock the request to the server
  return wait(Math.random() * 1000+500)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("generating a token");
      return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
    });
}

function getUserID(token) {
  console.log("getUserID(%o)", token);
  //mock the request to the server
  return wait(Math.random() * 1000+500)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("returning userId");
      return "id-1234";
    });
}

function getUserDetails(userId) {
  console.log("getUserDetails(%o)", userId);
  //mock the request to the server
  return wait(Math.random() * 1000+500)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("returning user");
      return {
        id: userId,
        firstName: "Zaphod",
        lastName: "Beeblebrox"
      }
    });
}


function postUserDetails(user) {
  console.log("postUserDetails(%o)", user);
  return wait(Math.random() * 1000+500)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("userDetails posted");
    });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this excellent answer, that should get me there. I am just struggling to understand where exactly the values are passed to the next function? is that implicit in the .then() that the return value is passed to the next function?

Comment: @NicoMüller yes. `then()` takes a callback that is executed with the resolved value **when** the value is available. And it returns a new Promise that resolves to the return value of that callback. You should take the time and learn Promises.

Comment: Hi, yes i have modified the postCall now to take an array as from what I read now only one parameter can be passed (as with returns of course).
Many thanks for your great help, i will study this in more detail now.